# Can i use SWR Hook with pure React / Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, swr

SWR Hook created by Vercel and it was recommending for Data fetching of Next.js
So can i use SWR Hook with pure React / Create React App ?

Comment: SWR hook is designed for Next.js. So you can't use it in React App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

The first [Basic Usage example](https://swr.vercel.app/examples/basic) of the [SWR Homepage](https://swr.vercel.app/) even contains an example of swr in a normal react app.